# Changing Local Folder, Affect Github?

Tags: git, github, directory-structure

I am a little new to Git and Github.

I have uploaded several projects to Github. Since then I have changed the folder structure on my local computer and moved the folders main location, consolidating some folders, etc. How will this affect my Git uploads in the future? Will the folders location automatically be updated or do I have to tell Git/Github where the folder it was tracking has moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it will make no difference. The Git repository is an invisible subdirectory and travels with its container (what you call "the folder it was tracking"). The paths from there downward  are all relative. If you changed something's location at a lower level, `git status` will tell you and the normal add-and-commit will handle it.

Do *not* edit any files until you've done that commit if needed. Moving a file and editing it, in one move, is a bad idea.

GitHub knows nothing of the matter. It just does what Git tells it to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to tell it, *Git* will track it automatically. But there are a few things to consider:

- Git doesn’t track empty folders
- All folders in this repository must be located below the `.git` folder, if the folder should be included in this Git repository

After reordering the folders, you must only add the changes (`git add .`), commit it (`git commit -m "Reordering folder structure"`) and push to GitHub (`git push`).